# Creating a card shuffling program Java

Tags: java, shuffle

I am trying to create a card shuffler within java that will perform "the perfect shuffle" (splitting the deck in two equal halves and interleaving each card, then repeating one more time), by performing both in and out shuffles. I have the following code to perform the shuffle.

```
public class Shuffle {

private static final int shuffleCount = 2;

private static final int valueCount = 52;

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Result of " + shuffleCount + "perfect shuffles" );

    int[] value1 = new int[valueCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < value1.length; i++){
    value1[i] = i;
}//ends valueCount for loop
    for (int j = 1; j <= shuffleCount; j++){
        riffleShuffle(value1);
        System.out.println(" " + j +":\n");
        for(int k = 0; k < value1.length; k++){
            System.out.println(" " + value1[k]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }//ends shuffleCount for loop
    System.out.println();
}

public static void riffleShuffle(int[] value){

    int[] temp = new int[value.length];
    int startFirst =  0;
    int startSecond = value.length / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i+=2){
        temp[i] = value[startFirst];
        temp[i+1] =value[startSecond] ;
        startFirst ++;
        startSecond ++;
}
    for (int i =0; i< value.length; i++)
        value[i] = temp[i];

}
```

}

I am trying to implement it into my deck class so rather than shuffle numbers 0-52, instead it will shuffle a deck of cards. My deck class looks as follows;

```
public class Deck {


private List<Card> cards;


private int size;//number of cards in deck


public Deck(String[] faces, String[] suits, int[] values){
   cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
   for(String suit: suits) 
       for(int value = 0; value < values.length && value < faces.length; value++){
           Card a = new Card(faces[value], suit, values[value]);
           cards.add(a);
       }
   size = cards.size();
   shuffle();

}//ends deck

public boolean isEmpty(){
    return cards.isEmpty() && size == 0;
}//ends isEmpty

public int size(){
        return cards.size();
}//ends size

public void shuffle(){
    for (int i = cards.size() - 1; i > 0; i--){
    int pos =  0;
    Card a = cards.remove(pos);
    cards.add(i, a);
    }

}//ends shuffle

public Card deal(){
    size --;
    Card a = cards.get(size);
    return a;
}//ends Card deal

@Override
public String toString(){
    String deck_rtn = "\nsize = " + size + "\n\nUndealt cards: \n\n";

    for(int k = size -1; k >= 0; k--){
        deck_rtn = deck_rtn + cards.get(k);
            if (k != 0){
            deck_rtn = deck_rtn + ", ";
            }//ends first if

            if ((size - k) % 2 == 0) {
            deck_rtn = deck_rtn + "\n";
            }//ends second if

    }

    deck_rtn = deck_rtn + "\nDealt cards: \n";
    for (int k = cards.size() - 1; k >= size; k--){
        deck_rtn = deck_rtn + cards.get(k);
        if (k != size){
        deck_rtn = deck_rtn + ", ";
        }
        if ((k - cards.size()) % 2 ==0){
        deck_rtn = deck_rtn + ", ";
        }
    }

    deck_rtn = deck_rtn + "\n";
    return deck_rtn;
```

I find my problems stemming from trying to implement it into my shuffle method within my deck class.

```
    public void shuffle(){
    for (int i = cards.size() - 1; i > 0; i--){
    int pos =  0;
    Card a = cards.remove(pos);
    cards.add(i, a);
    }

}//ends shuffle
```

anyone any ideas? All help greatly appreciated, thanks. PS. I am trying to avoid using the quick collection class method wherever i can, im new to java and want to understand things fully first before using collection classes.

Comment: As an aside: Look up [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). It is proven to produce a uniform distribution and only needs `O(n)` random numbers.

Comment: Ill be sure to look into that :) Just for this application i wanted to use the perfect shuffle as part of the card force trick, to call it the perfect shuffle is completely contradictory however it has many flaws, lol

Comment: What your code does is actually the Faro shuffle, if I'm not mistaken. :)

Comment: @Pateman upon Googling, I found out that the term "perfect shuffle" can refer to both Faro and Fisher-Yates (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_shuffle). I'd tend to call Fisher-Yates perfect rather than an algorithm that reproduces the original deck after 8 applications, but it's up for OP to decide what he wants.

Comment: @daniu Totally agree.

Comment: Both are referred to as perfect shuffles, i did express my opinion on the riffle/faro shuffle being called perfect previously

Comment: @Mgallagher That's true. In real-life scenario, it's much easier (at least in my experience) to perfectly interleave cards using the Faro shuffle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way (interleaving while spliting):

```
public void suffle(){

    //let's first split the deck in two
    List<Card> firstHalf = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Card> secondHalf = new ArrayList<>();

    while(cards.size() > 0){//we will split the cards while interleaving them
        firstHalf.add(cards.get(0));
        cards.remove(0);
        if(cards.size() > 0){
            secondHalf.add(cards.get(0));
            cards.remove(0);
        }
    }

    //now just put the two parts together
    cards = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < firstHalf.size(); i++){
        cards.add(firstHalf.get(i));
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < secondHalf.size(); i++){
        cards.add(secondHalf.get(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by the perfect shuffle. Is there anything wrong with java's Collections.shuffle method?

```
    List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>(52);
    Collections.shuffle(cards);
```

Comment: Trying to avoid using the collection class wherever i can mate, thanks for your help but

Comment: A perfect shuffle is when a deck of cards is split in equal halves and then each card is interleaved. The code within my shuffle class does it perfectly i just need to implement it into my deck class so it shuffles the actual deck of cards rather than a list of intergers.

Comment: This should have been posted as a comment; it is not an answer.

Comment: @kaya3 it is an answer.

Comment: It is not an answer; it is a question directed at the OP, and an acknowledgement of not understanding the term "perfect shuffle" which was used in the question. A "perfect shuffle" is not actually something random, so `Collections.shuffle` is not applicable.

Answer (score 2):

So, you want your deck (a table) split in 2 and then have it merged one card from each.

Here is how you can do it :

```
public static Object[] riffleShuffle(Object[] deck){
    if (deck.length < 2) return deck; // nothing to shuffle
    Object[][] split = split(deck);
    return merge(split[0], split[1]);
}

private static Object[][] split(Object[] deck) {
    Object[][] split = new Object[2][];
    int pivot = (deck.length + 1) / 2; //rounded up
    split[0] = copy(deck, 0, pivot);
    split[1] = copy(deck, pivot, deck.length);
    return split;

}

private static Object[] merge(final Object[] o1, final Object[] o2) {
    Object[] merged = new Object[o1.length + o2.length];
    for (int i=0; i<merged.length; i++){
        if (i%2==0) merged[i] = o1[i/2];
        else merged[i] = o2[i/2];
    }
    return merged;
}

private static Object[] copy(Object[] source, int start, int end){
    Object[] copy = new Object[end - start];
    for (int i=start; i < end; i++){
        copy[i-start] = source[i];
    }
    return copy;
}
```

`riffleShuffle(Object[] deck)` will accept any Object. You can call it like this :

```
Integer[] values = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};
Object[]  result = riffleShuffle(values);
if (result instanceof Integer[]) {
    values = (Integer[]) result;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));//[1, 8, 2, 9, 3, 10, 4, 11, 5, 12, 6, 13, 7]
}
```

You can change `Integer` by `Card` if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really understand what you're trying to do in your shuffle method, but here goes my suggestion:

First, you don't need `private int size;//number of cards in deck` in your deck since you can call `cards.size()`. Is is also not recommended, since your deck size and you list size could be different. Just stick with your size method: `public int size(){return cards.size();}` or in you case, since you're treating it always like a common deck of cards, you can just use a constant of 52.

But I don't really like fixed stuff, then the following method will shuffle a deck of any size:

```
public void suffle(){

    //let's first split the deck in two
    List<Card> firstHalf = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Card> secondHalf = new ArrayList<>();

    int halfSize = cards.size()/2;
    if(cards.size()%2 != 0){ //in case the number of cards is odd we have to add one more card to the first half
        halfSize += 1;
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++){
        if(i < halfSize){
            firstHalf.add(cards.get(i));
        }else{
            secondHalf.add(cards.get(i));
        }
    } //now we have a split deck, the firstHalf contains the top of the deck and the second half contains the bottom


    cards = new ArrayList<>();//empty the main deck to remake it

    while(firstHalf.size > 0){ //the first half will always be bigger or have the same size
        cards.add(firstHalf.get(0)); //always get the first card, since we will remove it next
        firstHalf.remove(0);
        if(secondHalf.size() > 0){ //now we are interleaving the cards
            cards.add(secondHalf.get(0));
            secondHalf.remove(0);
        }
    } 

    //now your deck is shuffled

}
```

**EDIT:**
I think I understood a little more what you wanted, take a look at this:

```
public static void riffleShuffle(List<Cards> value){

    List<Cards> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    int startFirst =  0;
    int startSecond = value.size() / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < value.size(); i += 2){
        temp.add(value.get(startFirst));
        temp.add(value.get(startSecond);
        startFirst ++;
        startSecond ++;
    }
    value = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i =0; i< value.size(); i++){
        value.add(temp.get(i));
    }   
}
```

Comment: Would this mean my riffleShuffle code can be disregarded? Thank you for your help sir.

Comment: Getting an error at  if(cards.size()%2), int cannot be converted to boolean

Comment: @Mgallagher edited the condition and also transformed your riffleShuffle to use Card direclty.

Answer (score 0):

Typical shuffles in programs are done with what is referred to as a `Fisher-Yates` shuffle, which randomizes a list of elements.  I presume you want to emulate a perfect shuffle where each card is iterlaced with the others.  Here is one way of doing that.

Most of this is boiler plate to demonstrate the method.  The method `mergeShuffle` is the one you may be interested in.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String suit = "CDHS";
      String rank = "KQJT98765432A";

      // create a deck of cards..
      String[] deck = IntStream.range(0, 52).mapToObj(
            i -> "" + rank.charAt(i % 13) + suit.charAt(i / 13)).toArray(
                  String[]::new);
      // show it
      display(deck);
      deck = mergeShuffle(deck);
      System.out.println();
      display(deck);
   }

   public static void display(String[] deck) {
      int i = 0;
      for (String card : deck) {
         System.out.print(card + " ");
         i++;
         if (i % 13 == 0) {
            System.out.println();
         }
      }
   }

   public static String[] mergeShuffle(String[] deck) {
      String[] shuffledDeck = new String[52];
      if (deck.length != 52) {
         System.out.println("You're not playing with a full deck. :)");
         return null;
      }

      int i = 0; // destination index of the shuffled deck
      for (int k = 0; k < 26; k++) {
         shuffledDeck[i++] = deck[k];
         shuffledDeck[i++] = deck[k + 26];
      }
      return shuffledDeck;
   }
}
```