# How to create a riffle shuffle in java using in-shuffle and out-shuffle

Tags: java, shuffle

I'm looking to create a riffle shuffle. I need to split my deck into two equal halves (top and bottom) and then merge the two halves together by interleaving single cards from the two halves. I have the deck created but I just dont know how to go about splitting it into two equal halves.

This is the code I have so far:

```
class Deck
{
    private static String[] suit = {"\u2660", "\u2666", "\u2663", "\u2764"};
    private static String[] rank = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};
    private static String[] deck = new String[52];

    // create deck
    static
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++)
        {
            deck[i] = rank[i % 13] + " of " + suit[i / 13];
        }
    }

    // un-shuffled deck
    static void deck()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++)
        {
            deck[i] = rank[i % 13] + " of " + suit[i / 13];
            System.out.println(deck[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you at least tried something?

Comment: Hint: to "split" the deck you don't actually need to create two separate arrays. Just pick a point that is the first card of the second half.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59397518/creating-a-card-shuffling-program-java

Answer (score 0):

Since your deck consists of 52 cards you must "split" it in two decks with 26 cards each. As Joachim said, you don't need to create a new array for that but can think of deck 1 starting at deck[0] and deck 2 at deck[25]. Next you will need to go through each of those decks one card after time and save the new shuffled deck.

```
static String[] shuffleDeck(String[] unshuffledDeck) {
    // Buffer for deck we want to return
    String[] shuffledDeck = new String[unshuffledDeck.length];
    // We start at index 0 for our first deck (lower half)
    int firstDeckIndex = 0;
    // We start at half of the maximum length of the total deck for our second deck (upper half)
    int secondDeckIndex = unshuffledDeck.length / 2;
    // We start going through the indexes of the new deck which we are going to return
    for(int shuffledDeckIndex = 0; shuffledDeckIndex < shuffledDeck.length; shuffledDeckIndex++) {
        // This is for alternating between the two decks. The modulo operator (%) returns the remainder of a division
        // 0 % 2 == 0 equals to true, 1 % 2 == 0 equals to false, 2 % 2 == 0 equals to true etc. 
        if(shuffledDeckIndex % 2 == 0) {
            // We put the current card of the first deck inside our new shuffledDeck
            shuffledDeck[shuffledDeckIndex] = unshuffledDeck[firstDeckIndex];
            // We advance the index to get the next card of the first deck
            firstDeckIndex++;
        } else {
            // Same as with the first deck
            shuffledDeck[shuffledDeckIndex] = unshuffledDeck[secondDeckIndex];
            secondDeckIndex++;
        }
    }
    // We return the new shuffled deck
    return shuffledDeck;
}
```

I recommend you to try implementing a new function yourself once you have grasped the concept itself.